# i want to invoke DropBox Api in my App to upload the files and download

Tags: iphone, dropbox

Any help How to invoke the dropbox Api to upload and down load different types of files...

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps

example given in this link is useful to download images only ..

any one can help me how to download the other types of files also ...

i dont have much exp with DropBox,as i am beginner to use this type of Api ...

Any help Appreciated

Comment: The answer that you accepted contains the same link you included in your answer. I think you would need to search deeper before asking questions ;) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On creating an app within the dropbox developer portal, you'll get the necessary API keys.
See:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps

There is also an iPhone SDK/ example app.

Comment: This is not an answer. Its exactly the same what is asked in question. And surprisingly it has 4 upvotes. I am flagging it.

Comment: @anonymous: Downvoting would be more appropriate.

Comment: @ThiefMaster : Thanks for indicating. :-)) I will keep in mind from next time. This time I already flagged.

Comment: hi there :) my answer has been accepted BEFORE the original question has been changed (see: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4451294/revisions ) .. IMHO this is now a completely new question.